# One page editable list in the simplest, neatest way

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, xml, content-management-system

I have a simple HTML/CSS/JS site built and just 1 page needs to have an editable list of events (add, remove, edit); each event would have title, mini-description, date, start time and end time. So essentially 6 fields if it was in a database (with an id). I could code a php login page, create a small mysql db with 1 table, 6 fields etc and then 1 php back-end page to edit it all but I'm wondering if there's an even easier way - maybe no database, updating XML or similar? A one table database seems a waste of having a database...

I'm all about learning the most streamline, lightweight way of building sites. I dislike just installing bloated CMS systems, plugins etc to get a job done, so I'm looking for a way to do this with minimal code and installation. I've done some Googling but most ways require installation of CMS type systems, a lot of unnecessary files etc. Does anyone have any suggestions? The site could be Windows or Linux hosted opening up varying languages.

Comment: you can use text files or csv file to read and update data...

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to do something like this, with more inputs.
http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/angularjs/#/ (the [source code](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/angularjs) can be find here)

This example is using [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). So no need for a server-side database. But it depends on what kind of consistency you're looking for.

The technology used is angularjs. I make you an example more lookalike what you want to do if you wish to.

Comment: angular is something I'd heard of but not read about - it looks pretty cool. 

I'm unclear on localStorage, is this like Cookies in that it is user specific or is it something one user (e.g. me) can update but every site visitor will see (tapping into those same localStorage values I've input)? 

I don't want visitors to update anything, just see what i've updated.

Comment: localStorage is a user side storage. So that is not what you are looking for. You are looking for a server side storage. I guess [redis](http://redis.io/) or [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) can be  what you are looking for. They are easy to use. Take a look to the nosql technologies.